# How can I add arrays into another array

Tags: c#

I'm having a trouble in having another set of arrays where I would like to combine the process, arrival and burst. Where the new array should gonna look like this
mat = {{process,arrival,burst}, {process,arrival,burst} ...

```
int process, temp;
double[] arrival = new double[100];
double[] burst = new double[100];
double[,] mat = new double[10, 6];

Console.WriteLine("Enter number of Process: ");
process = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter Arrival time of each process: ");
arrival = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), Double.Parse);

Console.WriteLine("Enter Burst time of each process: ");
burst = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), Double.Parse);  

for (int i = 0; i < process; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < process; j++)
    {
        mat[i,j]=  process[i], arrival[i], burst[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! To improve your chances of getting an answer please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your process is an int, how can you use process[i]? And your mat[i,j] expects a double, you can do something like mat[i,j] = arrival[i] + burst[i].

Comment: Concerning the array only, you can use a two-dimensional array, e.g. `mat` where
`mat[i, 0] = process`, `mat[i,1] = arrival` and `mat[i, 2] = burst`. I assume that you have only one `arrival` and one `burst` per process. If you have a one-to-many relation a more complex solution is necessary.

Comment: @KalleSvensson that's I would like to do, to create a two-dimensional array but I'm having a trouble how would I loop it to add the 3 arrays that I want to insert

Comment: In fact you don't need `mat[i, 0]` `process` because the row number in the array will be equivalent to the process number.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've probably reached the point where you should stop trying to keep things in separate arrays, associated by position and design a proper class for them to hold them in a cohesive way

For example:

```
public class X{
   public int ProcessId {get;set;}
   public List<double> Arrivals {get;set;}
   public List<double> Bursts {get;set;}
}
```

Or, if your arrivals and bursts are always numbered the same because the first arrival and the first burst are related (and the second burst/arrival are related etc), perhaps:

```
public class X{
   public int ProcessId {get;set;}
   public List<(double Arrival, double Burst)> ArrivalBursts {get;set;} = new();
}
```

Then you're populating them:

```
var x = new X();

Console.WriteLine("Enter number of Process: ");
x.Process = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter Arrival time of each process: ");
x.Arrivals = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(double.Parse).ToList();

Console.WriteLine("Enter Burst time of each process: ");
x.Bursts = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(double.Parse).ToList();
```

Or for the related ones perhaps:

```
var x = new X();

Console.WriteLine("Enter number of Process: ");
x.Process = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter Arrival time of each process: ");
var arr = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(double.Parse);

Console.WriteLine("Enter Burst time of each process: ");
var bur = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(double.Parse); 

if(arr.Length != bur.Length)
  ...error handling...

x.ArrivalBursts = arr.Zip(bur, (a,b) => (a, b)).ToList();
```

This `x` you have created can now go in a `List<X>`, so it's keeping its processid plus arrival times and bursts together in one unit, amongst many other different instances of the same

> look like this mat = {{process,arrival,burst}, {process,arrival,burst}

If this means that the processid is specified once, and then paired with multiple arrival-bursts (themselves associated positionally), then it could be like:

```
public class X{
   public int ProcessId {get;set;}
   public double Arrival {get;set;}
   public double Burst {get;set;}
}

...

Console.WriteLine("Enter number of Process: ");
var pid = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter Arrival time of each process: ");
var arr = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(double.Parse);

Console.WriteLine("Enter Burst time of each process: ");
var bur = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(double.Parse); 

if(arr.Length != bur.Length)
  ...error handling...

var all = x.ArrivalBursts = arr.Zip(
    bur, 
    (arr,bur) => new X{
      ProcessId = pid,
      Arrival = arr,
      Burst = bur
    }
  ).ToList();
```